# THE numbers speak for themselves

Tags: definite-articles

I have a short story headline called "Los Números Hablan Por Sí Solos", referring to the basic numbers from 0 to 9 in a calculator screen, but I wonder what is more correct: "The Numbers Speak For Themselves" or "Numbers Speak For Themselves"
Thank you for the better translation

Comment: Using an article refers to some prior knowledge, which might be a picture or a gesture. Using _numbers_ without an article is generic, and refers to mathematics or accounting, or anything that can be numbered or counted. In the context of a prior reference, _numbers_ can mean the same as _the numbers_, but there's no guarantee about how a reader will interpret a headline, since it's encountered before the story.

Comment: Are you being asked to translate the story into English? If so I would use the definite article because it appears in the original. The difference in the usage with or without the article in English is so minor as not to override the consideration of literal translation in this case.

Answer (score 1):

"The Numbers Speak For Themselves" = The numbers that I will mention or have mentioned speak for themselves.

"Numbers Speak For Themselves" = All numbers (or numbers in general) speak for themselves.

Without knowing the context of the story, it is not possible to say which is better: both are correct.

Comment: Careful. "The numbers (or figures) speak for themselves" is a fixed expression often used to mean "if you remain to be convinced, look at the statistics or financial accounts".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In the fixed expression, "The numbers (or figures) speak for themselves",  "the" = "of which we are both aware" However, in the examples, it is probably a play upon that well known expression.